# Using the estimated 96% interval, [0.48, 0.54], what conclusion would we reach if we test H0: P = 0.56 versus H1: P $\neq$ 0.56 at α = 0.04?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

ADDITIONAL INFO: According to a poll, (51%) of surveyed employees agree with the statement that the people
who run most companies are "honest and ethical."

- Already found the sample size to equal 1167

Found z= -3.44

Concluded to reject the null and accept the alternative, since -3.44 less than or equal to -2.05

Is my answer correct?

Comment: what is the standard deviation?

Comment: @P.J. 0.0145306

Comment: $z  = \frac{0.51-0.56}{\sigma \sqrt{1167}} = \frac{-0.05}{\sigma \sqrt{1167}}$ This is not equal to $-3.44$ unless $\sigma$ is very small

Comment: @P.J. I think the point is that $\dfrac{-0.05}{\sqrt{\frac{0.56\times0.44}{1167}}}=-3.44$

Comment: Please do not use the `probability-theory` tag for just about every question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is essentially correct, though you should show how you found $1167$ and $0.0145306$ and $-3.44$

When you have done that, you may be able to see that your argument is essentially that the confidence interval $[0.48, 0.54]$ does not cover the hypothesis value of $0.56$